# How to get the AxesImages from matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

all, I use the such code to plot the images

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(array,cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

however, now I want to get the handle  (`im`) of `im=plt.imshow(array,cmap='jet')`
How can I get the handle of `im` if I ignore the handle in the second step.

Comment: Please use the proper layout tools when writing a question, like formatting your code.

Comment: Why do you ignore the handle in the second step if you need it later?

Comment: Because I opened one window in one function and I want to get it in another function. Of course I can return the hadle and export it to another function, but it's not very convenient for me. Sometimes, I don't want to return the handle, then the handle will be printed on the screen that is what I don't want to have. So...,getting it by some codes are perfect for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can call the method `get_images()` on the `ax`.

Example code:

```py
ax = plt.gca() 
ax.imshow(array) 
ax.get_images() # returns a list of AxesImage objects if any.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can retrieve all the children present on the axes and filter on the object type.

Like:

```
ax = plt.gca()
imgs = [obj for obj in ax.get_children() if isinstance(obj, mpl.image.AxesImage)]
```

If you have only one AxesImage on the axes it returns a list containing one object, for example:

```
[<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7be6400>]
```